# c floating point round down

Tags: c, printf, rounding

If I run the following:

```
int tokenIdx=ERROR; //ERROR=8
tokens[tokenIdx] = 57; //tokens is of type int[]
int totalTokens = 100;
int percent = (int)((100.0 * tokens[tokenIdx])/(float)totalTokens);
printf("%d%\n",percent);

int percent2 = (int)(100.0*(tokens[tokenIdx]/(1.0*totalTokens)));
printf("%d%\n",percent2);
```

the output is:

```
57%
56%
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: float multiplication is not associative.

Comment: In binary floating point 57 cannot be divided by 100 exactly, 100*57 can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because 5700.0 and 100.0 can both be represented exactly as floating point numbers, and their ratio is exactly 57.0. On the other hand, 57.0/100.0 cannot be represented exactly as a floating pointer number, and multiplying it by 100.0 will not produced exactly 57.0. If it produces slightly less than 57.0 (as seems to be the case), then casting to `(int)`, which truncates, will result in the integer 56.

Comment: So you're saying:
    int percent2 = (int)(100.0*(tokens[tokenIdx]/(float)totalTokens)); //notice the float cast
will produce the same out put as the original?

Comment: I'm saying that the grouping of operations makes a difference. Changing the cast to multiplying by one does not.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point rounding error.  In your first case, you're doing a double divided by a float, in the second, it's a double divided by a double.  The int conversion is throwing away the fractional portion, which in the second case is probably .999999999998 or something like it.

**Lessons learned:** floating point isn't precise, mind your conversions, watch your types

If you really honestly want an integer percentage, do:

```
int percent = 100 * value / total;
```

where `value` and `total` are both ints.

If you need more precision (say 10ths), consider doing it in thousands or and dividing down to float:

```
float percent = (1000 * value / total) / 10f;
```

Provided that 1000 * value won't overflow in your problem domain.